# What is the best fingering for this passage of "fluttering intervals"?

Tags: piano, fingering

What is the best fingering to use for the following passage from "La Plage" by Yann Tiersen (section "B", mm. 7–12)?

It seems to me that the first measure should alternate 14-25, but this pattern is

- somewhat awkward
- not something that works well for the next measures

[image: Section "B", mm. 7-8]
[image: Section "B", mm. 9-10]
[image: Section "B", mm. 11-12]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To play as notated, with the double-notes handled entirely by the right hand, I use this fingering:

measure 7: 14-25
measure 8: 13-25
measure 9: 14-25
measure 10: 13-25
measure 11: 13-25 or 12-25
measure 12: 13-25

However, as an alternative, the passage flows quite comfortably by splitting the inner voice between the two hands. In each measure, the right hand plays single notes on the beat and double-notes on the half-beats. The left hand does the opposite, playing double-notes on the beats and single notes on the half-beats.

Here is measure 7 as an example. For the right hand, I use 5-13, and for the left hand I use 13-5 correspondingly. (The first left-hand note, of course is 5: thus, 5-5 13-5 13-5 13-5.)

[image: Tiersen, "La Page", section B, m. 7]